# Resolving Array of Promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, axios

I am working on a little project currently and have come across this issue.

Here's a little context of what I am doing. First, I make a call to an API concurrently with `Axios` like so:

```
const [...result] = await Promise.all([
 axios.post('api-url', data, headers),
 axios.post('api-url', data, headers),
 axios.post('api-url', data, headers),
 axios.post('api-url', data, headers),
])
```

Then I map through the result array and get back an array of objects just like the one below:

```
//data array
const data = [{name: 'john'}, {name: 'jane'}, {name: 'doe}]
```

Based on the data array listed above, I create new users in my MongoDB collection like so.

```
const result = data.map(async (item) => {
        return Promise.all([
            User.create({ name: item.name, }),
        ])
    })
```

Now, here is the problem - when I do a `console.log(result)`, I get an array of unresolved promises, e.g:

```
result [    
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } 
]
```

I don't know what's happening here. From my understanding `Promise.all()` is meant to return an array of resolved promises. What could I be doing wrong? And how do I resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you can get word of 200 status, then just run a queue, push the items however and async/await run through the function call the next item in queue when 200 is returned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know what's happening here, from my understanding Promise.all() is meant to return an array of resolved promises.

No. `Promise.all()` returns a promise which resolves when all the promises passed to it have resolved.

The *first* time you use it (in code block 1) you `await` the return value. `result` gets populated with the resolved values of all the promises passed to `Promise.all`.

The other time you have a variable called `result`:

> ```
> const result = data.map(async (item) => {
> ```

You populate it with the results of mapping some data through `async` functions.

`async` functions always return Promises, so you get an array of promises stored in `result`.

Inside that `async` function you do this:

> ```
>     return Promise.all([
>         User.create({ name: item.name, }),
>     ])
> ```

The use of `Promise.all` here is pointless. You only pass one promise to it in the first place.

You need to

1. Collect the promises returned from each call to `User.create`
2. Use `Promise.all` to get a single promise that resolves when they are all ready
3. Wait for that promise to resolve

Such:

```
const promises = data.map( item => User.create({ name: item.name }) );
const results = await Promise.all(promises);
```